# How do I send a file through a send port with the same name as the FileReceiveName in BiztalkAdministrationConsole?

Tags: biztalk

I receive an email with an attached file.

I retrieve the email through a receive location.

Retrieve the attachment through a pipeline.

Then I have a send Port that consumes the message from the pipeline.

I'd like the send port to publish the document with the same name the file had in the attachment.

I read that you had to use the macro %SourceFileName% when setting the file name in the send port configurations.

I tried that but the file name comes out as literally %SourceFileName%.

I stopped the send port to check what was the FileReceivedName and it is what I want.
[image: Message with Send Port stopped]

These are the Send Port Configurations.
[image: Send Port Configurations]

After I restart the send port the file that gets published.
[image: Result of File published]

Comment: Do you see the "Jump" in the Namespace in tracking?  That's not the correct File namespace.  Do you have any notion where that comes from?

Comment: @Johns-305 It was in the code of the class I wrote to describe the deassembler. I removed it, cleaned the project, changed the key, rebuilt, redeployed, changed the references and it still has the Jump in new messages

Comment: @Johns-305 I deleted the bin and obj folder. Closed visual studio and the namespace property disappeared. It's working now with %sourcefilename%. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

`%SourceFileName%` is macro for the `FILE.ReceivedFileName` message context property which is normally added to the message context by FILE or FTP adapter, but not SMTP. You can set this property yourself inside orchestration or your receive pipeline and then you will be able to use the `%SourceFileName%` macro on the send port.

Comment: I'm not using an orchestration, can I do it inside my custom receive pipeline?

Comment: sure, you can do it insidde your receive pipeline, too. i've updated my answer to avoid any future misinformation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can promote a context property(nor especially ReceivedFileName) in your pipeline and use a macro to get this property like what you did with ReceivedFileName. have a look on this **[thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d47acbda-27fe-4f4e-9a42-b6028bcc2614/propertypromotion-in-custom-pipeline-component?forum=biztalkgeneral)**:

Answer (score 0):

Get the attachment filename from mime-properties and promote ReceivedFileName property to get %SourceFileName% during sending.

```
  public IBaseMessage Execute(IPipelineContext pContext, IBaseMessage pInMsg) {

        IBaseMessagePart bodyPart = pInMsg.BodyPart;          

        if (bodyPart != null)
        {
            string fileName = (string)pInMsg.Context.Read("ReceivedFileName", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/file-properties");
            fileName = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            pInMsg.BodyPart.PartProperties.Write("FileName", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/mime-properties", fileName);                
        }

        return pInMsg;}
```